# Why has the interval changed from p-1 to p/2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know that there are $(p-1)/2$ quadratic residues in $Z_{p}^{\times} $. However, I am unsure how this means that the interval p-1 changes to p/2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because of your question before, that with $a$ also $p-a$ is a quadratic residue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first $S_p$ is the set of $a$s in $[1,p-1]$.  The second is the set of $a$s *and* $p-a$s with $a$ in $[1,p/2)$.  The line before, "if $a$ is a quadratic residue, so is $p-a$" means you can pair up the elements of the first $S_p$, which is what the second $S_p$ is doing.

I submit that the "$\{a,p-a : \dots$" notation is a little weird.

Example:  $13 \cong 1 \pmod{4}$.  The quadratic residues modulo $13$ are $1$, $3$, $4$, $9$, $10$, and $12$.  We can gather these into $S_p$ as : \begin{align*}
\{a &: a \in [1,p-1]\} &: &\{1,3,4,9,10,12\} \\
\{a, p-a &: a \in [1,p-1]\} &: &\{1,12,\ 3,10,\ 4,9,\ 9,4,\ 10,3,\ 12,1\} = \{1,3,4,9,10,12\}\\
\{a, p-a &: a \in [1,p/2]\} &: &\{1,12,3,10,4,9\} = \{1,3,4,9,10,12\}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Why exactly do we need to half the interval (p-1) to also include the set of p-a s which are quadratic residues?

Comment: You don't *need* to.  Your set-builder can appear to include each element twice, although you only end up with one copy of each.  It is a convenience to the reader to not mislead them into thinking the set is twice as big as it is.

Comment: @chloeloughan : Edited in an example.  Had you tried writing down an example so you could *see* what was happening?

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: I think there is a small mistake: $13-3=10$ rather than 11

Comment: @chloeloughan : You are correct.  Fixed.  Thanks!